# Is to possible to convert a cross table to list using XSLT transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transform

I have an intermediate XML document in application which looks like this

Sample Source XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Car>
    <COL1>Name</COL1>
    <COL2>White</COL2>
    <COL3>Black</COL3>
    <COL4>Red</COL4>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <COL1>BMW</COL1>
    <COL2>20</COL2>
    <COL3>10</COL3>
    <COL4>10</COL4>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <COL1>TOYOTA</COL1>
    <COL2>15</COL2>
    <COL3>18</COL3>
    <COL4>22</COL4>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <COL1>MERCEDES</COL1>
    <COL2>20</COL2>
    <COL3>*</COL3>
    <COL4>12</COL4>
  </Car>
</DocumentElement>
```

Which in table form looks like

```
| Name     | White | Black | Blue |
| -------- | ----- | ----- | ---- |
| BMW      | 15    | 18    | 22   |
| TOYOTA   | 15    | 18    | 22   |
| MERCEDES |  20   | -    | 12   |
```

I want to convert this XML document to simple list represented by Name, Colour, and quantity as below in table view

```
| Name    | Colour  | Quantity |
| ------- | --------| -------- |
| BMW     | White   | 20       |
| BMW     | Black   | 10       |
| BMW     | Blue    | 10       |
| TOYOTA  | White   | 15       |
| TOYOTA  | Black   | 18       |
| TOYOTA  | Blue    | 22       |
| MERCEDES| White   | 20       |
| MERCEDES| Blue    | 12       |
```

or the trasformed XML should look like

Sample Transformed XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DocumentElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                 xmlns:my="put-your-namespace-uri-here">
   <Car>
      <Name>BMW</Name>
      <Colour>White</Colour>
      <Quantity>20</Quantity>
   </Car>
      <Car>
      <Name>BMW</Name>
      <Colour>Black</Colour>
      <Quantity>10</Quantity>
   </Car>
      <Car>
      <Name>BMW</Name>
      <Colour>Blue</Colour>
      <Quantity>10</Quantity>
   </Car>
   <Car>
      <Name>TOYOTA</Name>
      <Colour>White</Colour>
      <Quantity>15</Quantity>
   </Car>
      <Car>
      <Name>TOYOTA</Name>
      <Colour>Black</Colour>
      <Quantity>18</Quantity>
   </Car>
      <Car>
      <Name>TOYOTA</Name>
      <Colour>Blue</Colour>
      <Quantity>22</Quantity>
   </Car>
   <Car>
      <Name>MERCEDES</Name>
      <Colour>White</Colour>
      <Quantity>20</Quantity>
   </Car>
      <Car>
      <Name>MERCEDES</Name>
      <Colour>Blue</Colour>
      <Quantity>12</Quantity>
   </Car>
</DocumentElement>
```

Is it possible to do this using XSLT transformation? Please guide.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: I see no Blue in your input???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="col" match="DocumentElement/Car[1]/*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="/DocumentElement">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Car[position() > 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="car" select="COL1" />
            <xsl:for-each select="COL2 | COL3 | COL4">
                <Car>
                    <Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$car"/>
                    </Name>
                    <Colour>
                        <xsl:value-of select="key('col', name())"/>                 
                    </Colour>
                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>                  
                    </Quantity>
                </Car>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```